# How to draw arcs at the base of vectors in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to represent a set of 5 vectors with sectors at their base like in the figure below using pgfplots. [image]

Comment: Welcome to SE! See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280540/problem-with-tikz an serve as starting point for your MWE

Answer (score 2):

Here is a plain Ti*k*Z way.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/wedge arrow/.style={code={
\tikzset{wedge arrow/.cd,#1}
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wedge arrow/##1}} 
 \draw[dashed,thick,fill=\pv{fill},fill opacity=0.5]
  (0,0) -- (\pv{alpha}-\pv{beta}/2:\pv{r}*\pv{R})
  arc[start angle=\pv{alpha}-\pv{beta}/2,end angle=\pv{alpha}+\pv{beta}/2,
    radius=\pv{r}*\pv{R}] -- cycle;
 \draw[-latex,thick,blue] (0,0) -- (\pv{alpha}:\pv{R});
 \fill (\pv{alpha}:\pv{R}) circle[radius=2pt];
}},wedge arrow/.cd,alpha/.initial=90,beta/.initial=60,
    R/.initial=2cm,r/.initial=0.5,fill/.initial=gray!30]
\path pic {wedge arrow={alpha=15,r=0.4}}
 pic {wedge arrow={alpha=40,beta=50,r=0.6}}
 pic {wedge arrow={alpha=65,beta=60,r=0.5}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The pic `wedge arrow` accepts several parameter: the angle of the arrow, `alpha`, the opening angle of the wedge, `beta`, the radius, `R`, and the ratio between the radius of the wedge and `R`, `r`.