# How to types of angles and label specific angles

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to recreate something like this in overleaf. How would I go about do this? Also, how would I go about adding any specific angles if needed?

I am using the exam document class.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 11in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-0.8,-1.2)--(-3,-3)--(0,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Thank you so much!

Comment: Overleaf has nothing with your problem. It is just LaTeX editor, For recreating showed images among other possibilities look `tikz` package and its library `angles`.

Comment: For starting point see my answer on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280540/problem-with-tikz.  Hereon site are plenty of similar examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with the `angles` tikzlibrary, which you can copy almost literally from the [pgfmanual](https://tikz.dev/library-angle).

Hints:

- class `standalone` is better for development
- find the key adaption under `% development`, ...
- which is moved up into a `pics-style`, which accepts 1 parameter (angle)
- I called that style `angl`
- for the code statement see [18.3 Defining New Pic Types in the pgfmanual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-pics#sec-18.3)
- later, just use `\pic at (0,0) {angl={50}};`, just like nodes, with specifying both style and parameter inside `{ }`
- the last one just draws the pic twice, with `[rotate=180]`
- feel free to adjust color and radii

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    pics/angl/.style args={#1}{%#1 = angle in deg
        code={
            \draw   (0:1) coordinate (A) -- 
                    (0,0) coordinate (B) -- 
                    (#1:1)  coordinate (C)
                pic [fill=blue!60!green!40,angle radius=7mm] {angle=A--B--C};       
        }
    }
 ]
    % development
%   \draw   (0:1) coordinate (A) -- 
%           (0,0) coordinate (B) -- 
%           (30:1)  coordinate (C)
%       pic [fill=blue!60!green!40,angle radius=7mm] {angle=A--B--C};
    
    \pic at (0,0) {angl={50}};  
    \pic at (3,0) {angl={90}};  
    \pic at (6,0) {angl={120}};     

    \pic at (0,-3) {angl={180}};    
    \pic at (3,-3) {angl={210}};    
    \pic at (6,-3) {angl={180}};    
    \pic[rotate=180] at (6,-3) {angl={180}};    
    
 \end{tikzpicture}  
  
\end{document}
```

#### Using this code with other documentclasses

Just change the beginning, like so:

```
%\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 11in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    pics/angl/.style args={#1}{%#1 = angle in deg
...
```

I.e.

- remove the standalone class (here via comments)
- put in yours
- add `\usepackage{tikz}`, which was loaded implicitely in my statement
- there you go

[image: resultExam]

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for this! I actually cannot use another document class because it is on a document where the rest of the test is. Is there any way to do it in the exam class?

Comment: Just copy the code using your class, or compile this code with exam, article etc. It may happen that horizontal space becomes an issue after compile.

Comment: @user292225, kindly have a look at my recent comment and at the add-on to my answer.