# Drawing an angle in simple tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm tyring to make a very simple tikz drawing for an orthogonal projection of two vectors, but I can't make a round angle.
Can someone help me with that please?

My current code is the following:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
\tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt]


\draw [->, line width=1.2] (0,0) -- (30,0);
\draw (22,0) node [below, yshift=-0.3cm] {$u$}; 

\draw [->, red, line width=1.2] (0,-2) -- (15,-2);
\draw (7.5,-3) node [below, text=red] {$p$}; 

\draw [->, line width=1.2] (0,0) -- (15,15);
\draw (7.5,7.5) node [above left, yshift=0.5cm] {$v$}; 

\draw [dotted, line width=0.75] (15,15) -- (15,0);

\draw [black] (13,0) -- (13,2);
\draw [black] (13,2) -- (15,2);


\draw [-, bend left=80] (3,3.5) -- (7,0);
\draw (6,2.5) node [above right] {$\Theta$}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

which produces the following drawing:

[image: Current drawing]

Comment: A quick search could have been useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578359/add-a-theta-angle-inbetween-axes-and-a-line-using-tikz/578449#578449

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `calc` library for the projection and the `angles` library for the angles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,nodes={inner sep=0pt},>=latex]
 \draw [<->, line width=1.2] (30,0) coordinate (u)
     --  node[pos=0.3,below=1ex] {$u$} (0,0) coordinate(o)  
     -- node[pos=0.5,above left=1ex] {$v$} (15,15) coordinate (v);
 %
 \draw [dotted, line width=0.75] (v) -- ($(o)!(v)!(u)$) coordinate (p);
 %
 \draw [->, red, line width=1.2] (0,-2) -- node[pos=0.5,below=1ex] {$p$}
  ($(p)+(0,-2)$);
 %
 \pic[draw,angle radius=3em,angle eccentricity=1.3,pic text={$\Theta$}]{angle=u--o--v}; 
 \pic[draw,angle radius=1.5em]{right angle=u--p--v}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for always coming back.

Comment: @Werner Who are you and what do you mean? If you need help, there are better resources.

Comment: @Werner How can you tell?

Comment: @ user237902 I don't know who you are but the answer is +1.